# Forcing command on ssh's authorized_keys merges STDOUT and STDERR

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, redirection, stdout, stderr

I've been working to have a script in a centralized server to do some things and output a .tar.gz file (see [redirect temporarily STDOUT to another file descriptor, but still to screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/379798/redirect-temporarily-stdout-to-another-file-descriptor-but-still-to-screen)). I also have exchanged ssh keys, so now from a client machine I can execute the script in my main server and output the result to a .tar.gz file in the client while seeing all the other output (STDERR) of the script:

```
me@client:~$ ssh auto@remoteserver /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh > content.tar.gz
// shows the output of the STDERR here...

me@client:~$ tar ztf content.tar.gz
content/file.txt
content/foobar.txt
...
```

But if I force the execution of this command putting the command option in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
#/home/auto/.ssh/authorized_keys file
command="/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh",from="client" ssh-rsa 0UYmshd5FSDFf2fd...
```

and execute the following, it does not work:

```
me@client:~$ ssh auto@remoteserver > content.tar.gz
// shows **NOTHING**

me@client:~$ tar ztf content.tar.gz
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

if I look into the file, it contains both the `STDERR` and the `STDOUT`. Any idea why it is getting mixed? And more importantly, any idea on how to avoid this?

**ps**: I should mention that `myscript.sh` is a wrapper for the main script, that basically calls the main script with a set of fixed params:

```
#!/bin/sh
# myscript.sh: wrapper for mainscript.sh to use by the user auto with ssh-keys
/usr/local/bin/mainscript.sh foo bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first way you invoke the command doesn't create a pty, while the second may or may not. Try telling sshd not to create a pty. In your authorized_keys file:
`command="/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh",from="client",no-pty ssh-rsa...`

If you want to ssh from the command line when the `no-pty` option is set in your `authorized_keys` files you must redirect the STDIN to read from `/dev/null` or you would get an error saying `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0`:

```
$ ssh auto@remoteserver < /dev/null > content.tar.gz
```

If instead you do the `ssh` command without a controlling terminal, there's not STDIN available and you can omit the `< /dev/null` part. So in cron you might do the following without problem:

```
0 4 * * * ssh auto@remoteserver > content.tar.gz
```

Comment: No, that didn't work :(. It gave error `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0`

Comment: Hm wait yes, it does work. If I try to ssh directly from the command line it gives me the previous error, but if I redirect STDIN from /dev/null, it does not give the error and everything works ok. I suppose that running this from a cron script will also work without needing the redirection, as it will be called without a controlling pty.